# Prove that merge sort outputs a permutation of the input

Tags: algorithm, sorting, mergesort, divide-and-conquer, correctness

I am beginning to study Computational Logic, and as an exercise, I want to prove the correctness of merge sort algorithm.

Currently, I’m having difficulties to prove that the output of this algorithm will always correspond to a permutation of a given input.

I’d be very glad if someone can assist me with this.

Thank you very much

Comment: The output of any sort is a permutation of the input. If it isn't, then the sort is broken.

Comment: Nobody disputes that, Jim. This question is about *proving* that merge sort isn't broken.

Answer (score 1):

The core of this proof will need to show that the "merge" procedure inserts each element once and only once into the result. Since the merge procedure works using a loop, you need to use a [loop invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_invariant) to show this.

Loop invariants can usually be discovered by asking, "what do I know *halfway through* the loop?"

```
to merge arrays A and B:
    let n = length of A, m = length of B
    let R = new array of length (n + m)
    let i = 0, j = 0
    while i < n or j < m:
        if i < n and (j == m or A[i] <= B[j]):
            R[i+j] = A[i]
            i = i + 1
        else:
            R[i+j] = B[j]
            j = j + 1
    return R
```

In this loop, we always know that the first i+j elements of R are some permutation of the first i elements of A and the first j elements of B. That's the loop invariant, so you need to show that:

1. This is true before the loop starts (when i = j = 0).
2. If this is true before an iteration of the loop, then it remains true after that iteration, i.e. the invariant is preserved.
3. If this is true when the loop terminates (when i = m, j = n), then the array R has the required property.

In general, the hard parts of a proof like this are discovering the loop invariant, and showing that the invariant is preserved by each iteration of the loop.

Comment: "In this loop, we always know that the first i+j elements of R are some permutation of the first i elements of A and the first j elements of B." Wouldn't this proof need to show that A and B were constructed from R as a lemma? Also probably need to make one of the loop invariants that the intersection of A and B is the null set. Great answer though, +1.

Comment: Merge sort does not require the input array to contain no duplicates, so there is no need for the arrays A and B to be disjoint (and the proof isn't easier if you make this assumption). The concept of a permutation is well-defined for sequences with duplicate elements. In the pseudocode I gave, R is constructed from A and B, not the other way round; but if you meant it's necessary to also show that A and B get their values from the input list, you are right, of course. There are a lot more details required for a full proof; I just focused on the main task in this answer.

Comment: tbh proving theorems and constructing lemmas has always been a weakness of mine. I had to prove the validity of a transitive closure algorithm in college a few years ago and the prof had to hold my hand a little bit. It also never occurred to me to do merge sort iteratively ("bottom-up") instead of recursively, so I had a specific version of the algorithm in my head when I answered. (The transitive closure proof was just nested loops. I've never proved the correctness of a recursive algorithm, only implemented them with passing grades.)

Answer (score 0):

What are the preconditions of a merge sort? What are the post conditions? Do you have any loop invariants?

These are the three questions you have to ask yourself before you can start writing your proof.

Then: what are your base cases? Presumably you know how merge sort works if you are working on a proof, so what happens when you have an array of length 1 passed to the mergesort function? What is the postcondition there?

Here's a [decent primer from Berkeley](http://www-inst.cs.berkeley.edu/~cs170/fa14/tutorials/tutorial1.pdf) on how to prove the correctness of a function. It might take some discrete math (induction) to write the proof.

Comment: Without knowing specifics of the algorithm / implementation, or even top down versus bottom up, how do you prove that no data is lost in some auxiliary buffer or temporary storage, and that all of the input elements end up in the output elements (which is usually back to the input)? I assume that potential issues like a user defined compare function throwing an exception isn't being considered for this question.

Comment: @rcgldr I'm a bit confused, you mean how do you prove the algorithm will be correctly implemented by its executing software and hardware?

Comment: I meant how to prove an algorithm without resorting to some implementation specific details. For example, the Wiki description of merge sort : "Divide the unsorted list into n sublists, each containing one element (a list of one element is considered sorted). Repeatedly merge sublists to produce new sorted sublists until there is only one sublist remaining. This will be the sorted list."  Then kaya3's answer, which is a specific implementation of merge.

Comment: Generally speaking, you need to choose an implementation, or a pseudocode implementation, to have something specific enough to prove any results about. But if you can prove it for one implementation, then your method of proof can probably be adapted to other implementations in a straightforward way. The loop invariants will be the same (but perhaps written in different notation), for example.

Comment: @kaya3 assuming you did a recursive divide and conquer, how would that complicate the proof (or simplify it)? My answer was in terms of a recursive algorithm with a base case of a single element (which is obviously a sorted array by definition).

Comment: I think the proof is much simpler for the recursive form. The core of the proof is still proving the merge procedure correct; the recursive function itself is quite short, since it just handles the base case, or otherwise slices the list, recursively sorts them (correctly, by induction on the list length), and then merges them (correctly, by the proof of the merge procedure).

Comment: @kaya3 cheers, writing proofs has always been a weakness. Thanks for the tips.